# What's the meaning of this line from an American TV drama?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

So here is a line I couldn't understand from the TV drama Manifest (2018)

**[Look, I don't understand. I was trying to race to you so I can get you my research off of the portal.]**

Said by a medical researcher to her superior. And her superior answered:

[I got your research five years ago.]

--------background info line------------------

SO I know [get you my research off] means give my research to you, **but what's the meaning of [of the portal]?**

The researcher was one of the passengers of a commercial airliner who suddenly reappear after being presumed dead for five years. It would be nice if anybody can answer, I'm an English learner~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The portal" is an electronic tool that the junior researcher uses to store or disseminate her research.

I do not work in the medical field so it is not clear to me exactly what this portal is in this context, but a portal in computing is an electronic resource (usually a website) that compiles other websites or indexes resources from a other locations. In this case presumably this refers to a research paper written previously by the junior character that was published or circulated and is most easily accessed through the portal that medical researchers customarily use.

Comment: That's exactly what I need!  I can understand this line now, thank you very much!